# How to disable all components in html till a ajax listener method complete the process?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to call a ajax listener  `<p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="business_promoter_representedBy_panel, title_panel" listener="#{promoterBean.handleContactSelected()}" />` . When i run the application on local host it's works fine. After I deployed in web this method get long time to complete the process . So before it complete user may click the save button . If do so it's tell null point exception. So i need to disable all component until the process complete. Can anyone help on this ??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Analyze the avaiable components in the primefaces showcase

Comment: I show those components i tried with <p:blockUi and <p:lightBox but i couldn't find a solution @Kukeltje

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly, you do not want the user to click save button till ajax finishes?

in such a scenario, replace the save button with a dummy save button when you fire the ajax and on success replace the original save button which has the action....

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are correct . But can you help with an example ? Because i am new to prime faces  and ajax.

Comment: okay fine Thank you. I find a way to do this. I used <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!targetBean.step1}" > for my works .